# What happens if I find all the Pixel Toads?

Tags: captain-toad-treasure-tracker

After you complete a level, you get the option to redo it, but this time you are looking for a Pixel Toad hidden somewhere in the level.

I have figured out that doing this and finding the Pixel Toad gets you a gold stamp on that level's page, but do I get anything extra if I find all of the Pixel Toads, or even a certain number? Or do I just get the gold stamps to show off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Finding the Pixel Toad on every level within an episode book will also adorn the cover with a golden Pixel Toad.

Source: [GameFaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/wii-u/805615-captain-toad-treasure-tracker/cheats)

It appears you just get a golden Pixel Toad on the cover.

Here is the final result:
[image]

As shared by a user of Reddit.

[Original Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/amiibo/comments/2zwtwi/this_is_what_you_get_for_finding_all_the_pixel/)